# Unable to change dropdown value using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on **Reactjs/Nextjs** and right now I am trying to change the dropdown value (working on the update module).

I tried the following code but it's not working.

```
const Post =  function(props) {
    const [content2, setContent2] = useState('');
    }

useEffect(()=>{
    setContent2(post?.cat_name);
},[])

 <select value={post?.cat_name} className="form-control" name="cat_name" id="cat_name" onChange={(con2) => 
    {
        setContent2(con2);
    }}>
                          
 <option value="">Select Category</option>
    <option value="pined"  >Pined</option>
 </select>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Where is `post` coming from?

Answer (score 1):

use `content2` as value

```
value={content2}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can initialize content2 in declaration

```
 const [content2, setContent2] = useState(post? post.cat_name : "");
```

then the value attribute in select should be content2 also in onChange try to use event

```js
<select
  value={content2}
  className="form-control"
  name="cat_name"
  id="cat_name"
  onChange={(event) => {
    setContent2(event.target.value);
  }}
>
  <option value="">Select Category</option>
  <option value="pined">Pined</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `disabled` only accepts `true` or `false`. It doesn't accept functions.